# For a graph $C_n$, why do we have $\lvert\operatorname{Aut}(C_n)\rvert \geq 2 |R| = 2n$?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

In the book of *Algebraic Graph Theory* by Godsil, at page 8, it is stated that

[image]

However, the group $\langle g\rangle$ is of order $n$ and the group $\langle h\rangle $ is of order 2, so shouldn't we have 
$$|Aut(C_n)| \geq n+2$$
 ? I mean I couldn't understand the argument that the author makes. Can some help me to understand the reason why we have 
$$|Aut(C_n)| \geq 2 |R| = 2n$$
?

Comment: $\langle g\rangle$ has order $n$, and $h\langle g\rangle$ also has order $n$. They are disjoint subsets of $\text{Aut}(C_n)$, giving the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the automorphisms
$$
1,g,g^2,\dots,g^{n-1}
$$
there are also 
$$
h,hg,hg^2,\dots,hg^{n-1}
$$
making for at least $2n$ automorphisms. The first list is $R$, the second list is the set $hR=\{hr:r\in R\}$. This is called a *coset* of R, and is the second coset that text mentions.

Comment: And there aren't any more...